# I need a regex for email that does not allow following country code eg cu,ir,sd,sy,kp

Tags: regex

Currently I am using regex

```
^\w.*@\w+\.\w+[^(ir)|(cu)|(sd)|(sy)|(kp)]
```

regex mismatch for single chars like i,r,c,u,s,d,s,y,k,p

But I need to mismatch it for strings ir,cu,sd,sy,kp

From this i can mismatch

```
asingh@gmail.cu
asingh@gmail.sy
asingh@gmail.hu
```

but i dont want it for `asingh@gmail.hu`

Comment: If you want single characters, then add character class for them

Comment: i want to make regex mismatch for string like cu,sd,sy,kp

Comment: Can you please provide some example inputs? What should match, and what should not

Comment: form this i can mismatch asingh@gmail.cu  asingh@gmail.sy and also asingh@gmail.hu but i dont want it for asingh@gmail.hu

Comment: mismatch for anychar@anychar.cu , anychar@anychar.sd ,anychar@anychar.sy, anychar@anychar.kp , anychar@anychar.ir

Comment: after DOT cu, sd, sy,kp should be mismatch by regex only these strings

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add additional information rather than comments

Answer (score 0):

You can use `x(?!y)` quantifier. It matches the character combination `x` if and only if it is not followed by the character combination `y`.

The final regexp could look like this:
`/^\w.*@\w+\.(?!(ir|cu|sd|sy|kp))/`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and clearest way of doing this will be to use two regular expressions: one to check the format of the email address, and a separate one to check whether it ends in a sanctioned TLD, e.g.

```
if (email matches /^\w.*@\w+\.\w+$/
    and email does not match /\.(ir|cu|sd|sy|kp)$/) {
  ...
}
```

Additionally, your first regular expression (which I have not corrected) will reject email addresses at domains which contain hyphens (like `test@example-example.com`), and at domains with more than two components (like `test@example.co.uk` or `test@like-this.example.com`). You will want to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

E-mail regex are notorious for tradeoffs.

I got this one to work for your TLDs, while sticking with your basic method. I'd advise tweaking, as duskwuff suggests (note the mismatches [here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iuqhoD/2)), but that depends on your situation.

```
^\w.*@(?!(\w.+\.)?(ir$|cu$|sd$|sy$|kp$)).*
```